# Create setup file automatically uninstall existing setup and install new setupfile without changing the existing version property on setupfile

Tags: c#

By setting the bellow properties we can create the setup file automatically uninstall existing setup and install new setupfile.

DetectNewerInstalledVersion:True
RemovePreviousVersion:True

But each and every setup file we need to change the version property of Setupfile. If it is, it won't through error while installing current setupfile otherwise
it throws error: already installed.

I am looking into how we can create the setup file without changing the version property of existing setupfile.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question seems odd. When you want to detect an already installed version, and want to make an update, why you would not like to have a new version number? How a previous version should get detected then?

Answer (score 1):

This is not what you want to hear, but if you are deploying updates with the same version, you are doing it wrong. It might look easy and convenient now, but it will cause you a lot of headaches later.

Why don't you try to start doing it right and version your updates correctly?.

Perhaps what you need is to learn is how to automate your version number and setup program generation. Post a question about that and fix it once for all.

good luck.